# SAS Google Map Generator, safe on secure data?

Tags: google-maps, sas, geocoding

I want to use the SAS Google Map Generator but I am not sure if I can on proprietary data. I don't want any of the data to be placed anywhere but my own server, even when interacting with Google.

Ideally what I want is to download the map of my choice (state of Wyoming for example) and all of the locations of that area are in a zip file or shape file for me to be able to pin the dataset locations onto, in my own computer. I was reading [this](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/025-2010.pdf).
But it seems a bit confusing to me. Has anyone used it and know that I wouldn't be sending any of my information back to Google?

I've never done this before so I just want to be sure I won't get in trouble for any data leaks.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2014/06/06/spice-up-sas-output-with-live-google-maps/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Google Maps API, as it seems you are, then yes, you are sending some information to Google - namely, the center of the map that you're displaying, plus possibly other information depending on what exactly you are displaying.

If you want to do everything client-side, the easiest way is likely to use SAS's built-in map files.  This won't display a Google Maps style map, and will give up quite a bit of detail, but it will allow you to display the state borders, counties, and major cities.

You also could use OpenStreetMaps or a similar product, which is locally downloadable more or less as you describe.  However, you wouldn't be able to use the Google Maps API; you'd have to do the projecting in SAS still.

Comment: Yea I may just try to use OpenStreetMaps. I think you are right in that information is sent back, the application has to communicate back to the maps server somehow to capture the location of the lat longs. Thanks. I'll delve deeper into the Openstreetmaps. Too bad. :/

Comment: You aren't sending Google the lat/long of the points that are being displayed, that is all local to the client.  It is only if you are using a service (like the geocoder, KmlLayer, the directions service, etc), that you send data to the Google Servers.

Comment: @geocodezip Are you sure?  At least some of the API papers I've seen using SAS are passing the individual points.

Comment: I don't much about SAS, does it use the Google Maps Javascript API v3?

Comment: SAS is a general purpose programming language, so I imagine it can use whatever API they choose to implement.  What it's doing is creating HTML pages and making calls from there.  It looks at a glance like you have to tell Google where to display the map (where its center is), but not where the specific points are?  Edited to modify that language slightly.